# Vote to re-open 2 year old question?

Tags: support, reopen-request

I just edited this question, then noticed it was two years old (Community User put it back in a queue).

[I need help! PopUp with only OK button](https://superuser.com/questions/605463/i-need-help-popup-with-only-ok-button)

Looks like a perfectly valid question to me. It could do with some more information, which is unlikely to come now.

Should I vote to reopen?

Comment: Doesn't an edit to a closed question automatically put it into the Reopen queue?

Comment: It's offtopic for [su] anyway.

Comment: The question is about the user interface on an iPod which is out of scope for Superuser.  Furthermore if the question needs more information then it should be provided BEFORE you vote to open it.

Comment: Ah, I missed that iPad issies are off-topic here. I though the close vote reason was incorrect (which I why I was thinking about re-opening before the additional info).

Comment: Here is the reason the question was closed, "Questions on Super User are expected to relate to computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined by the community.", based on the fact the question is about the Apple iPad in such a way it is outside of the scope defined by the community - Here is just one of the question, asked in that question, *Can I have two browsers on the same Ipad, or will I loose all my favorites and stuff from Safari?* seems like the correct decision was made.  If you disagree with a close reason on a 2-3 year old question best to come into chat and ask.

Comment: I left a comment on the question, but it's worth raising it here.  Questions that are closed automatically pop up in a review queue to confirm that they should remain closed.  So a closed, old question has been officially pronounced dead.  The community bot recycles old questions lacking an accepted answer on the chance that they will receive new answers.  For the vast majority, the OP is long gone, so any new answers won't be accepted, either.  But that's another issue.  The point is, closed questions cannot receive new answers.  Why on earth is the bot recycling these?

Answer (score -2):

There is no value in re-opening this question, because it has already received a comprehensive and valid answer. It does not really matter that the OP never accepted it as a solution. Let this question rest in piece, don't bring it back to life

Comment: Hmm, I can't say I agree with the last sentence - It would seem to go against the common SE paradigm of constantly improving upon and updating questions & answers. We're not a forum, we don't hate old posts, the system has even been written to automatically 'bump' questions which it deems as needing attention. Now I'm not advocating that this particular question gets reopened (because a. It's about iPads, and b. It's requires some clarification from the OP), but in general, closed questions should either be updated and reopened, or deleted. Having them sit closed isn't doing anyone any favours